# Why Lombok @Cleanup use [Collections.singletonList().get(0)]?

Tags: java, lombok

I don't understand why lombok use singletonList, here is a demo:

```java
@Cleanup FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream("aa.txt");
```

after build:

```java
FileInputStream fos = new FileInputStream("aa.txt");
try {
   fos.read();
} finally {
   //I think [fos != null] should be better
   if (Collections.singletonList(fos).get(0) != null) {
       fos.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project Lombok developer here.

We're working around linter tools that warn about a useless null check. For normal generated methods we just tag the method with a `@SuppressWarnings` and any other annotation your linter tool may need to realize it shouldn't complain about it, but that can't be done with `@Cleanup`.

Comment: I'd like to use [fos!=null] instead, I just want to know what difference is , more efficient.

Comment: It'd be more efficient but I seriously doubt you'd notice; the cost of for example opening and closing a file is literally billions of times higher than that list creation.

Comment: well,  if u say so, I shouldn't care about this, thanks! Wait, FileInputStream is a example, how about other Streams (or it's not a Stream, like connection, graphics etc.)?

Comment: Most resources are orders of magnitude more expensive in nature.